# How to kill reverseTimer at this

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Can you tell me how to kill this Timer, so after that i can create new timer again

```
  public void reverseTimer(int seconds, final TextView tv)
    {
        new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000 + 1000,1000)
        {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                tv.setText(String.format("%02d",minutes)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds));
            }

            public void onFinish(){
                tv.setText("Completed");
                Intent myintent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
                myintent.putExtra("total",String.valueOf(total));
                myintent.putExtra("correct",String.valueOf(correct));
                myintent.putExtra("incorrect",String.valueOf(wrong));
                startActivity(myintent);
            }
        }.start();
```

how to create kill/cancel function at this

Comment: do you want to kill it before it is consumed?

Comment: no, i start the countdown first, aftre that i want to delete it because the quiz going to next question, after the second question i want to create new countdown. Just how to delete the countdown

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO community.

You can create a field for the `CountDownTimer`, and invoke `.cancel()` to get it over & renew it again by using your method reverseTimer(). 
and use a boolean to track whether the quiz question is ansewred by the user or not; When they answer it, then call restartTimer() to go to the next question

```
private CountDownTimer mTimer;
private boolean mIsAnswered = false;

public void reverseTimer(int seconds, final TextView tv)
{
    if (mIsAnswered) {
        mIsAnswered = false;
        nextQuestion();
        return;
    }
    mTimer = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000 + 1000,1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tv.setText(String.format("%02d",minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds));
        }

        public void onFinish(){
            nextQuestion();
        }
    }.start();
}

public void restartTimer() {
    if (mTimer != null)
        mTimer.cancel();

    mIsAnswered = true;
    restartTimer(...);
}

public void nextQuestion() {
    tv.setText("Completed");
    Intent myintent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("total",String.valueOf(total));
    myintent.putExtra("correct",String.valueOf(correct));
    myintent.putExtra("incorrect",String.valueOf(wrong));
    startActivity(myintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private CountDownTimer timer;

timer = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000 + 1000,1000){
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                tv.setText(String.format("%02d",minutes)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d",seconds));
            }

            public void onFinish(){
                tv.setText("Completed");
                Intent myintent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
                myintent.putExtra("total",String.valueOf(total));
                myintent.putExtra("correct",String.valueOf(correct));
                myintent.putExtra("incorrect",String.valueOf(wrong));
                startActivity(myintent);
            }
        };

timer.start();

private void cancelTimer(){
    if(timer !=null){
    timer.cancel();    
    }
}
```